# example of locally finite type not finite type

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a ring then, a homomorphism $A\rightarrow A[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ induces a finite type morphism between spectrums.
I want to find the map which is a locally finite type but not finite type....

Comment: Try $k[x]\rightarrow k(x)$.

Comment: Dear Marci, $k[x]→k(x)$ is the inclusion?? Then, $\operatorname{spec}k(x)=\{0\}$... so is $\operatorname{spec}k(x) \rightarrow \operatorname{spec}k[x]$ is finite type??

Comment: The map $k[x]\rightarrow k(x)$ is not of finite type, $k(x)$ is not finitely generated $k[x]$-algebra.

Comment: sorry... but then is this map locally finte type???

Comment: Assume k is algebraically closed. Then every maximal ideal is given by $x=a$ for some $a\in k$. Then locally (for example around 0) $k[x]$ becomes $k[x]_{(x)}$. Moreover $k(x)$ is finitely generated over $k[x]_{(x)}$, you only need to add $1/x$.

Comment: The comments by Marci are wrong. For morphisms of affine schemes, locally of finite type = finite type. Affine morphisms are quasi-compact.

Answer (score 10):

A morphism is called of finite type if it is quasi-compact and locally of finite type. If $f_i : X_i \to Y$ are morphisms of finite type for $i \in I$, then clearly the induced morphism $f : \coprod_{i \in I} X_i \to Y$ is locally of finite type, but it is usually not of finite type when $I$ is infinite. So, for example, if $A$ is any commutative ring $ \neq 0$, then the canonical morphism $\coprod_{n \geq 0} \mathrm{Spec}(A) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ locally of finite type, but it is not of finite type.

Comment: Why the downvote?